# Style <ui:inpucheckbox> with SLDS

Tags: lightning, slds

How can we apply slds to `<ui:inputcheckbox>`.I tried using `<ui:inputcheckbox class="slds-checkbox" value=""/>` but no hits.I want to style the checkbox as of SLDS.
Also i am using other way around `<lightning:input type="checkbox"/>` which is styled as SLDS by default but i think due to beta version it is giving me following error.

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
>   Aura.loadComponent(): Failed to initialize application. An internal
>   server error has occurred Error ID: 1853269181-216614 (1023342491)

Comment: Can you post the exact markup you tried to use for <lightning:input type="checkbox" />? We are using that component extensively without issues.

Comment: Just instead of using <ui:inputcheckbox> i was using <lightning:input type="checkbox" click="{!c.Change}"/> which returns me the error i posted.

Comment: If that is true, then you were missing required attributes. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm

Answer (score 1):

Sometime you'll see that error when you are missing attributes. lightning:input requires name and label. Try:

```
<lightning:input type="checkbox" name="check1" label="Check Please" />
```

If you don't want a label, Summer '17 added a no label variant:

```
<lightning:input type="checkbox" name="check1" label="Check Please" variant="label-hidden" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For applying SLDS styling try the following code with ui:inputCheckbox:

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <label class="slds-checkbox">
            <ui:inputCheckbox value="" />
            <span class="slds-checkbox--faux" />
            <span class="slds-form-element__label">Checkbox</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    </div>
```

It will work for sure. If this helps mark it as best answer.

Comment: Dude i have got through that already.See in my answer post.I have different query.However thanks for your reply